# Can this be done a better way?

Tags: c

[Just playing around doing some exercises in visual studio, and I managed to make this work but I feel it can be done in a better way, without having to type something so many times. I was thinking maybe a for loop could do the job but cant get my head around it. Any ideas?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSMGp.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculate_pizza_share(int number_of_people);

int main() {
  int num_of_people;

  printf("how many people are shairng this pizza? ");
  scanf("%d", &num_of_people);

  calculate_pizza_share(num_of_people);

  return 0;
}

int calculate_pizza_share(int number_of_people) {
  if (number_of_people == 1) {
    printf("You get %d slice(s) each\n", 8 / number_of_people);
  } else if (number_of_people == 2) {
    printf("you get 4 slice(s) each\n");
  } else if (number_of_people == 3) {
    printf("you get 2 slice(s) each\n");
  } else if (number_of_people == 4) {
    printf("you get 2 slice(s) each\n");
  } else if (number_of_people == 5) {
    printf("you get one slice(s) each\n");
  } else if (number_of_people == 6) {
    printf("you get one slice(s) each\n");
  } else if (number_of_people == 7) {
    printf("you get one slice(s) each\n");
  } else if (number_of_people == 8) {
    printf("you get one slice(s) each\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code?

Comment: `printf("You get %d slice(s) each\n", 8 / number_of_people);`

Comment: Put the code in the question, why would you post a link to a screenshot of your editor?

Comment: because apparently my formatting is incorrect and the editor wants me to add code to places

Answer (score 2):

How about a single line:

```
printf("You get %d slice(s) each\n",8 / number_of_people);
```

You don't get the "one" instead of "1", but I think the simplicity overrides that.

In lieu of that, the entire `if/else` "ladder" can be replaced with `switch/case`

---

**UPDATE:**

> fixed the issue I had with the editor, code is now in the post.

Okay, here are both ways. I think the single line is still the best, but I've replaced the ladder with a `switch`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int calculate_pizza_share(int number_of_people);

int
main()
{

    int num_of_people;

    printf("how many people are shairng this pizza? ");
    scanf("%d", &num_of_people);

    calculate_pizza_share(num_of_people);

    return 0;
}

int
calculate_pizza_share(int number_of_people)
{

#ifndef SWITCH
    printf("You get %d slice(s) each\n", 8 / number_of_people);
#else
    switch (number_of_people) {
    case 5:
    case 6:
    case 7:
    case 8:
        printf("You get one slice each\n");
        break;
    default:
        printf("You get %d slice(s) each\n", 8 / number_of_people);
        break;
    }
#endif
}
```

Comment: Note that if you had put the code in a code block on this page, I'd have posted a `switch/case` example, but I didn't [and few others would] want to type it all in by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the chain of `if/else if` is the right way to go, especially when generating English phrases involving numeric quantities. But look for ways to reduce the number of conditions. In this example, you really only have three (valid) conditions

- 1 person: gets the whole pizza
- 2,3, or 4 persons: integer math drops the fractional part of a division, so `8/number_of_people` will give the right answer for all of these
- 5,6,7,8: integer division gives the correct answer, but the message is different, so treat these as a separate condition

In addition, you should always assume that the user will type nonsense (when given the opportunity). So you need to check the return value from `scanf`, and be prepared to handle numbers that are less than 1 and greater than 8.

With that in mind, here's what the code looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void calculate_pizza_share(int number_of_people)
{
    if (number_of_people < 1)
        printf("You need some people to eat that pizza\n");
    else if (number_of_people == 1)
        printf("You get the whole pizza\n");
    else if (number_of_people <= 4)
        printf("You get %d slices each\n", 8 / number_of_people);
    else if (number_of_people <= 8)
        printf("You get one slice each\n" );
    else
        printf("You need to order more pizza\n");
}

int main( void )
{
    int num_of_people;

    printf("how many people are sharing this pizza? ");

    if (scanf("%d", &num_of_people) != 1)
        printf("Was hoping for a number between 1 and 8\n" );
    else
        calculate_pizza_share(num_of_people);
}
```